# How are NUMERIC types serialized in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, rust, binary, low-level

I am building an interface for Postgres in Rust. My problem is serializing an u128 type into a numeric(40) type, but I cannot find the correct binary format for postgres. I tried serializing as both little and big endian with no success.

Comment: It is documented in the source code. They are binary coded decimals. Why don't you use the text format?

Comment: `UUID` ([Doc](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype-uuid.html)) has 128 bit :D

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I'm not using text format because I need to be able to perform numeric queries on the data. Could you point me to where in the source code the serializing format is documented?

Comment: @leun4m The problem is not representing 128 bits in postgres, that can be done with numeric(40). The problem is serializing a rust u128 type when sending the data over to postgres

Answer (score 1):

The binary format of `numeric` is not documented in the online documentation. You have to resort to the source code for that.

What you need is in [`src/backend/utils/adt/numeric.c`](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/utils/adt/numeric.c). The code that produces the network representation is [here](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/utils/adt/numeric.c#l1078). The data type is stored as [`NumericData`](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/utils/adt/numeric.c#105), and the representation used to do arithmetic is [`NumericVar`](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=blob;f=src/backend/utils/adt/numeric.c#l253).